# Export mermaid chart from DiagrammeR

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, diagrammer, mermaid

I'm attempting to export a Gantt chart from `mermaid` to a file through R. I'd be happy with any file format, but SVG or PNG would be preferable. I'm trying to automate this, so simply pressing export through the GUI is not an option.

Here's my code:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
graph <- mermaid("
    gantt
    dateFormat  HH:mm:ss.SSS
    title Sample Test Gantt

    section A
    thing1          :   15:58:51.556,   16:05:23.494

    section B
    thing2          :   16:02:00.391,   16:20:46.533

    section C
    thing3          :   16:18:57.352,   16:23:10.700
    thing4          :   16:24:11.705,   16:30:30.432
    ")
graph
```

And the graph it generates:
[image: A sample Gantt chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know about `mermaid` it is not possible yet to export to `svg` or other formats. But it is possible to dump many `mermaid` objects to an HTML via Rmd:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "August 1, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
## R Markdown
This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(DiagrammeR) 
   graph <- mermaid("
   gantt
   dateFormat  HH:mm:ss.SSS
   title Sample Test Gantt

   section A
   thing1          :   15:58:51.556,   16:05:23.494

   section B
   thing2          :   16:02:00.391,   16:20:46.533

   section C
   thing3          :   16:18:57.352,   16:23:10.700
   thing4          :   16:24:11.705,   16:30:30.432
   ")
graph
graph
graph
```
````

It produces an HTML file with all the graphs in it. Not an optimal solution, but better than trying to produce lots of charts manually.

Answer (score 5):

> This is a reported issues with the `DiagrammeR` package, so you may want to keep an eye on this page for future updates: https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/66

There are two ways this could be done as a workaround:

### Using Webshot

An alternative way of saving the file is to use the `webshot` package. This uses the external dependency phantomjs to convert the HTML widget to an image. It can be setup as follows:

```
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

Using your above example:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)


gannt %>%
  htmltools::html_print() %>%
  webshot::webshot(file = "gannt.pdf")
```

This will save the plot as a PDF, but you can create images by changing the filename i.e. `gannt.png`.

### Using the plotly package

The plotly package has a useful function for exporting HTML widgets:

```
plotly::export(gannt, file = "mermaid.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Marked mysteRious' answer as correct, as it really helped. For anyone in the future that runs into the same issue, here's the full solution I used:

Export.Rmd

````
---
title: "TestingExport"
author: "me"
date: "August 2, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(DiagrammeR) 
graph <- mermaid("
                 gantt
                 dateFormat  HH:mm:ss.SSS
                 title Sample Test Gantt

                 section A
                 thing1          :   15:58:51.556,   16:05:23.494

                 section B
                 thing2          :   16:02:00.391,   16:20:46.533

                 section C
                 thing3          :   16:18:57.352,   16:23:10.700
                 thing4          :   16:24:11.705,   16:30:30.432
                 ")
graph
```
````

Then use the following command to turn this into HTML:
`Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('...\\Export.Rmd')"`

Comment: I am not entirely sure why you need the two files? Have you tried using the `knit` button in RStudio?

Comment: @MikeyHarper I'm automating it so I'm calling this from a java file. I didn't end up needing the two files though, just used the following command:
`Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('<filepath>')"`